# Card-like design, with flexible heights

Tags: html, css

let's imagine a webshop, listing products:

```
 PICTURE  PICTURE  PICTURE
 PRICE1   PRICE1   PRICE1
                   PRICE1
 buy      buy      buy
```

the third product has two prices for example, they cant be fixed heighter (the widths are fixed), and the "buy me" button must be put at the bottom. How to do this, possibly with no tables?

Comment: I guess floating `div`s and `min-height`.

Comment: I was created a basic thing with <div> and <p> elements, but thats all. How do a card to know what is the biggest size in that row?

Answer (score 1):

If you use a separate row for the `buy` you don't need to worry about setting heights.

**CSS**

```
<style type="text/css">
    .row {
        width: 600px;
    }

    .col {
        float: left;
        width: 200px;
    }

    .clear {
        clear: both;
    }

</style>
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col">
        picture <br />
        price
    </div>
    <div class="col">
        picture <br />
        price
    </div>
    <div class="col">
        picture <br />
        price<br />
        price
    </div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
</div>



<div class="row">
    <div class="col">
        buy
    </div>
    <div class="col">
        buy
    </div>
    <div class="col">
        buy
    </div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
</div>
```